# Trying to create a dynamic hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, hyperlink

```
=HYPERLINK(c:\Users\tminnick\Desktop\("#FileName",A159)_EmploymentAgreement.pdf)
```

This is the link that returns an error message.  the `("#FileName",A159)` formula is intended to pull the text in `A159`, which is the first part of the full filename.  There are 168 records.

Thank you.

Comment: What should the hyperlink end up as were your formula working correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Use concatenate:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("c:\Users\tminnick\Desktop\",A159,"_EmploymentAgreement.pdf"))
```

Concatenate will just stick all the strings provided as parameters into one long string, which Hyperlink will then happily accept.

Comment: Closer, thank you very much.  This is what I get:  c:\Users\tminnick\Desktop#FileNameAdamJacobs_EmploymentAgreement.pdf.  the #FileName" shouldn't be there.

Comment: Just remove the string you don't want and edit as you wish... it's just an example.  I'll edit my answer anyway.

Comment: Rock Star you are.  This works wonderfully.  Thank you jehad.

Comment: You're welcome!  Have fun learning Excel.